# Plotting time on the x-axis with Python's matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, time, graph

I am reading in data from a text file which contains data in the format (date time; microVolts):

e.g. 07.03.2017 23:14:01,000; 279

And I wish to plot a graph using *matplotlib* by capturing only the time (x-axis) and plotting it against microVolts (y-axis). So far, I've managed to extract the time element from the string and convert it into *datetime* format (shown below).

I tried to append each value of time into x to plot, but the program just freezes and displays nothing.

Here is part of the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ecg = open(file2).readlines()

x = []
for line in range(len(ecg)):
    ecgtime = ecg[7:][line][:23]
    ecgtime = datetime.strptime(ecgtime, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S,%f')
    x.append(ecgtime.time())
```

I'm aware the datetime format is causing the issue but I can't figure out how to convert it into float/int as it says:

*'invalid literal for float(): 23:14:01,000'*

Answer (score 1):

I have no reputation for comment than I have to answer.

`datetime.datetime.time()` converts to `datetime.time` object, you need float.
Could you try `datetime.datetime.timestamp()`?

See last line:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ecg = open(file2).readlines()

x = []
for line in range(len(ecg)):
    ecgtime = ecg[7:][line][:23]
    ecgtime = datetime.strptime(ecgtime, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S,%f')
    x.append(ecgtime.timestamp())
```

EDIT: `timestamp()` is available sine Python 3.3. For Python 2 you can use

```py
from time import mktime
...
    x.append(mktime(ecgtime.timetuple()))
```

Comment: Hi rysson, I just tried it but it gives me:

AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: Function `datetime.datetime.timetamp` is new in version 3.3. For older you need to use time.mktime(ecgtime.timetuple()).